# Automatically redirect mails in Outlook folder while still being notified

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I work in a software company and I often end up being involved in several projects at once. My strategy to not get overwhelmed and being able to follow the conversations on the different projects is to separate the mails in different folders.

That works well, but it was a pain to move all the mails manually in the corresponding folders. I decided to automate it by creating a rule that moves a mail to the corresponding folder when the name of a given project is in the mail subject. For example:

[image: Outlook rule example]

That works well, but that creates another problem: the little mail symbol on the Outlook icon in the task bar does not appear when a new mail is moved to another folder than the inbox. I keep missing mails because of that...

Is there a way to automatically move a mail to a folder while still being notified of it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your initial configuration of the rule, you can specify an alert of a new element, i'm attaching a pic of my Outlook rules, they should be in the same spot even if my Outlook has another language.

[Rule alerts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvCeh.png)